# I am using python 3 for imaging and training the model using SVM. But I am getting the error when i run it "KeyError: 'NU '". How can i solve this

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-learn

**What does error mean KeyError: 'NU' and how to solve this**
i really  can't find the  right solution. i have 2 classes with "u" and "UN" 
all code work properly but the last section **Accuracy of mySVM model** gives the error. i also added the classWisedata

```
CLASSES = len(np.unique(labels))
print(CLASSES)


"""Function to Create the dictionary of labels as Keys 
    and their corresponding list of images as Values """

def classWiseData(x,y):      
    data = {}

    for i in range(CLASSES):
        data[i] = []

    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        data[y[i]].append(x[i])

    for k in data.keys():
        data[k] = np.array(data[k])

    return data


def accuracy(x,y):

    count = 0
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        prediction = predict(x[i])

        #Checking Predictions with Labels
        if(prediction==y[i]):
            count += 1

    return count/x.shape[0]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data = classWiseData(image_data,labels)
svm_classifiers = trainSVMs(image_data,labels)

print("Accuracy of mySVM model: ",accuracy(image_data,labels))

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-231-3a65bb35ee50> in <module>
----> 1 data = classWiseData(image_data,labels)
      2 svm_classifiers = trainSVMs(image_data,labels)
      3 
      4 print("Accuracy of mySVM model: ",accuracy(image_data,labels))

<ipython-input-214-329a3085304d> in classWiseData(x, y)
     13 
     14     for i in range(x.shape[0]):
---> 15         data[y[i]].append(x[i])
     16 
     17     for k in data.keys():

KeyError: 'NU'

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


from sklearn import svm

svm_classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear',C=1.0)

svm_classifier.fit(image_data,labels)

print("Accuracy of sklearn SVM model: ",svm_classifier.score(image_data,labels))s

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

please help me on this This. i am working first time on SVM

Comment: Provide the definition of `classWiseData()` function

Comment: Can you provide the definition of ```classWideData()``` and ```trainSVMs()```? Also why are you defining your own accuracy function? Can't you use the I built functionality of sklearn?

Comment: 'CLASSES = len(np.unique(labels))
print(CLASSES)


"""Function to Create the dictionary of labels as Keys 
    and their corresponding list of images as Values """

def classWiseData(x,y):      
    data = {}
    
    for i in range(CLASSES):
        data[i] = []
        
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        data[y[i]].append(x[i])
    
    for k in data.keys():
        data[k] = np.array(data[k])
        
    return data'

Comment: dear Pure-Entropy  please provide your email id s can i send you the full code to solve my probleam

Comment: mySVM = SVM()

def trainSVMs(x,y):
    
    svm_classifiers = {}
    for i in range(CLASSES):
        svm_classifiers[i] = {}
        for j in range(i+1,CLASSES):
            xpair,ypair = getDataPairForSVM(data[i],data[j])
            wts,b,loss = mySVM.fit(xpair,ypair,learning_rate=0.00001,maxItr=1000)
            svm_classifiers[i][j] = (wts,b)
    
                #plt.plot(loss)
                #plt.show()
            
    return svm_classifiers